# Get all rows from a sheet, into another sheet, where each row contains a cell matching a certain value

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a solution without VBA due to work limitations.

The schema of my sheet is as follows:

```
SheetName: 'Spend Track'
Row 4 - headings
A     B           C         D            E        F     G        H      I    J
Date, Originator, Supplier, Description, Receipt, Type, Account, Gross, GST, Net

Row 5 onward is data.
```

In another sheet (called `Kevin`); I want all the rows from Spend Track! that 
match the condition `Bx='Kevin'`. Where x= the given row number.

So if Spend Track has 10 rows, 3 of which belong to Kevin. The sheet `Kevin` will have 3 rows and will update when new rows are added in `Spend Track`.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd love to- but the boss wants an excel solve :(

Comment: U RIGHT IDK WHAT I WAS THINKING

Comment: I don't understand the **Bx='Kevin'. Where x= the given row number.** part. Why are we giving a row number, don't you want all the rows that have Kevin condition. And where will we check the Kevin condition in "Spend Track". And finally, is there a limit for the number of rows to be copied to the "Kevin" (or such) sheet(s)?

Comment: Similar Q:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010265/how-to-add-multiple-conditions-when-using-array-formula-with-index-and-match/50010538#50010538

Comment: Life would be great if we ever had some sample data and desired output sample :)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is to get a list going in Kevin of the row numbers you need. Following the hint of Tim Williams, here is a way. In some work column of the "Kevin" sheet (that can be hidden later if needed), where I will use column "A", create a column starting in row 4 (or put a header in row 3, first), to keep things simple, that says in its top filled in cell, `=if('Spend Track'!B4="Kevin",row(),1000000)`, where a million is comfortably bigger than the number of rows in the first sheet will be. This gives you a column of either the row numbers with Kevin in them (your x's) or a million.
Now in another work column parallel to the first, B in my example, but not needing to be quite as long, starting in the same row, do, and drag down, `=small(A$4:A,ROW()-3)`, and presto, you get a list of the row numbers with Kevin in them, followed by millions.
Once you have the row numbers, INDEX, will do the rest. Where you want your outputs to begin, put in `=index('Spend Track'!A:A,$B4)`, drag right until it becomes `=index('Spend Track'!J:J,$B4)` and down as many rows as you can imagine wanting matches.
This will give you all the desired rows.
On a Google Sheet, the references beyond the end of Spend Track leave things blank, but it appears that in Excel you will get a row of unsightly 0's. If that is so and it bothers you, the formula can be adapted to `=if($B4=1000000,"",index('Spend Track'!A:A,$B4))`
That should do it.